# Can I think about SymmetricAlgorithm as a factory of ICryptoTransform?

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, encryption-symmetric

I'm using SymmetricAlgorithm (AesCryptoServiceProvider in particular) to encrypt and decrypt a lot of messages.

(NOTE: pseudo-code)

```
parallel-foreach (var message, key, iv in triplets) 
{
    using (var algorithm = CreateAes())
    using (var transform = algorithm.CreateEncryptor(key, iv))
    {
        // do stuff using transform
    }
}
```

I do not mutate `algorithm` after it is created, and the only interaction with it is using it to `CreateEncryptor` using it as `ICryptoTransform` factory.

When I move the creation of algorithm out of the loop:

```
using (var algorithm = CreateAes())
{
    parallel-foreach (var message, key, iv in triplets) 
    {
        using (var transform = algorithm.CreateEncryptor(key, iv))
        {
            // do stuff using transform
        }
    }
}
```

I get 5-times performance improvement and it does work as expected, so it is worth trying.

What I cannot find if `SymmetricAlgorithm` is thread safe in such scenario. I'm not mutating it myself, but may it does happen behind the scenes?

Answer (score 1):

The construction and disposal of `AesCryptoServiceProvider` are not light weight. That is why you see the performance boost when you do not instantiate it within the loop:

```
    [System.Security.SecurityCritical]
    public AesCryptoServiceProvider () {
        Contract.Ensures(m_cspHandle != null && !m_cspHandle.IsInvalid && !m_cspHandle.IsClosed);

        // On Windows XP the AES CSP has the prototype name, but on newer operating systems it has the
        // standard name
        string providerName = CapiNative.ProviderNames.MicrosoftEnhancedRsaAes;
        if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major == 5 && Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor == 1) {
            providerName = CapiNative.ProviderNames.MicrosoftEnhancedRsaAesPrototype;
        }

        m_cspHandle = CapiNative.AcquireCsp(null,
                                            providerName,
                                            CapiNative.ProviderType.RsaAes,
                                            CapiNative.CryptAcquireContextFlags.VerifyContext,
                                            true);

        // CAPI will not allow feedback sizes greater than 64 bits
        FeedbackSizeValue = 8;

        // Get the different AES key sizes supported by this platform, raising an error if there are no
        // supported key sizes.
        int defaultKeySize = 0;
        KeySizes[] keySizes = FindSupportedKeySizes(m_cspHandle, out defaultKeySize);
        if (keySizes.Length != 0) {
            Debug.Assert(defaultKeySize > 0, "defaultKeySize > 0");
            KeySizeValue = defaultKeySize;
        }
        else {
            throw new PlatformNotSupportedException(SR.GetString(SR.Cryptography_PlatformNotSupported));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Release any CAPI handles we're holding onto
    /// </summary>
    [System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        Contract.Ensures(!disposing || m_key == null || m_key.IsClosed);
        Contract.Ensures(!disposing || m_cspHandle == null || m_cspHandle.IsClosed);

        try {
            if (disposing) {
                if (m_key != null) {
                    m_key.Dispose();
                }

                if (m_cspHandle != null) {
                    m_cspHandle.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
        finally {
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
```

As far as thread safety, from the documentation:

> Any public static ( Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are
>   thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread
>   safe.

If you dig into the source code, you can see there is no thread safety built into it.

Sources:

[Reference Source for .NET 4.7.1](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Security/Cryptography/AesCryptoServiceProvider.cs,6b3c2c2cf88c1df6,references)

[AesCryptoServiceProvider Class Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aescryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Quick pseudo-code to implement your algorithm while respecting the thread-non-safety of Aes instance members:

```
using (var algorithm = CreateAes())
{
    parallel-foreach (var message, key, iv in triplets) 
    {
        ICryptoTransform transform;

        lock (algorithm)
        {
            transform = algorithm.CreateEncryptor(key, iv);
        }

        using (transform)
        {
            // do stuff using transform
        }
    }
}
```